# Estimate server load for an API

Tags: php, mysql, api

I want to know how many resources (MySQL time, CPU usage, bandwidth, etc.) will use my system with a certain number of API calls per second.

One API call gets the parameters in PHP, do from 1 to 5 SQL queries and returns a XML file.

How I can do that? Any idea of a formula or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) PHP extension to do some profiling. It will tell you things such as how much time is spend on each function call, memory used, CPU used, etc. Do a few runs with it and you should have a good idea about the resources you are using. I've found it to be one of the most useful tools available in PHP. For more info, see the [this documentation](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html).

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to do this is by benchmarking it. It depends entirely on what your code is doing - I could write an SQL query that takes minutes to run, and I could write an SQL query that takes milliseconds.